# How to query all values for a SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue type using the SharePoint REST API v1?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, taxonomy, taxonomyfieldvalue

I need to query custom metadata properties for quite a lot of items from an on-premise SharePoint server. Therefore, I do want to work with a list, as shown in the article [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest), and not query each item individually.

I currently use a HTTP GET request with the URL `https://sharepoint.example.com/web/lists/getbytitle('Example')/items?$select=*&$orderby=ID&$top=50` and the header `Accept: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8`.

This works so far. I got a working query and I am now able to start parsing the JSON data returned by the query.

The JSON string returned contains a lot of `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` fields, both single-value (`example_single_value`) and multi-value (`example_multi_value`).

```
"example_single_value": {
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"
  },
  "Label": "1",
  "TermGuid": "<...>",
  "WssId": 1
},
"example_multi_value": {
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "Label": "Foo",
      "TermGuid": "<...>",
      "WssId": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I am aware of a SharePoint bug regarding single-value `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` fields as described in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/116210). This bug is not topic of this question and I'll try to find a workaround for this later.

Because all data needs to be migrated to another system, I'd like to query all **values** for each of the `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` types. In other words, I'd like to perform multiple HTTP requests using the SharePoint REST API v1, whereas each HTTP request returns all values for a named `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` type, e.g. `example_single_value`.

Example: Consider the values `abc` and `def` are used for the `example_single_value` type and the values `Foo` and `Bar` are used for the `example_multi_value` type.
I'd like to execute two HTTP requests for this example:

1. The 1st request for `example_single_value` would return `{"abc", "def"}`.
2. The 2nd request for `example_multi_value` would return `{"Foo", "Bar"}`.

How can I query all values for a `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` type with a HTTP request?

I wasn't able to find anything about this on the WWW, but I'm pretty sure that this must be possible, because the SharePoint frontend is also able to show a list of the `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` types.

**Edit 1:** I've found out that SharePoint creates one hidden list called `TaxonomyHiddenList` for the root site of a site collection. Querying this list does seem to return all **used** `SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` values. Sadly, this does not seem to group the values per category, but only global. This seems to be used by SharePoint as a performance optimization, in order to perform look-ups using the `TermGuid` and `WssId`. Therefore, this does not seem to be good enough, because I need to query the values grouped: Otherwise, I do not know to which category each value belongs.

**Edit 2:** It does not seem to be possible to query all taxonomy values using the SharePoint REST API v1. I've just found the following related questions and websites:

- [How to get all possible values of a TaxonomyField?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/26514/111319)
- [How to get Taxonomy field value list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/230580/111319)
- [Rest API to return all Terms and their GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/280862/111319)
- [Querying SharePoint Term store with REST API and I’m not joking..](https://medium.com/@ankitgirgas/querying-sharepoint-term-store-with-rest-api-and-im-not-joking-3e158dc31e08)
- [Querying managed metadata using REST (unsupported)](https://www.techmikael.com/2017/07/querying-managed-metadata-using-rest.html)

I've read that it is possible with the SharePoint REST API v2.1. Sadly that one isn't available on the instance I'm using

Hopefully I can find an answer (does not need to be using the REST API v1), how-to query all taxonomy types and all their values. I'd like to avoid to have to modify JavaScript on the site or use a C# API...

**Edit 3:** I've tried using the [TaxonomyInternalService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee586267(v=office.15)) with Java (Apache HttpClient), but I always get the following response from the POST request to `<site_url>/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetChildTermsInTermSetWithPaging`:

```
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

Here is the relevant Java source code:

```
final var json = """
    {
        "lcid": 1033,
        "sspId": "be4642a1-514e-4769-a9c2-e0ed28e36039",
        "guid": "7906ac77-dee0-4980-9320-0985adca1150",
        "includeDeprecated": false,
        "pageLimit": 1000,
        "pagingForward": false,
        "includeCurrentChild": false,
        "currentChildId": "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000",
        "webId": "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000",
        "listId": "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000"
    }""";

final var request = new HttpPost(String.format("%s/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetChildTermsInTermSetWithPaging", this.siteFullUrl));
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=verbose;charset=utf-8");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
request.setHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
request.setHeader("X-RequestDigest", this.formDigestValue);

final var requestEntity = new StringEntity(json);
request.setEntity(requestEntity);

final var responseBody = execute(request);
```

I assume "I'm almost there", but I don't know what to modify in order to fix the request.